# Issue with onLocationChanged(Location loc) & ASync Task in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, reverse, geocode

I have an android app that connects to the internet to do a reverse geocode on lat and long co-ordinates in real time.  This lags the UI and can cause it to give a "not responding - force close/wait" error(as expected without using async/ threads-handlers!)

I have implemented an Async Task which works very well(no more UI lag!), but variables set inside the onLocationChanged method (that sets them to the latitude & longitude) are inaccessible. 
The class I am doing this in, is linked to another seperate class that passes the variables and can send an sms to a person which includes the reverse-geocoded address.
However, since implementing the Async Task using the doinbackground method, I can no longer send what I need.  I don't know if I can explain any better, I will provide sample code.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){
    mylat = loc.getLatitude();
    mylong = loc.getLongitude();
}

/*
afaik, this is the code that does the internet stuff, that lags the 
UI.  If I put this in doinbackground, it cannot access mylat & my long, 
and the "loc.getLatitude" has to be done in the "onLocationChanged" 
method, which HAS to exist. If I leave the ListAddress code outside the 
doinbackground, everything works, BUT the UI will obviously lag.
*/
List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(mylat,mylong, 1);
```

Can anyone advise the best way to get `mylat = loc.getLatitude(); & mylat = loc.getLatitude();` inside the doinbackground method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Override the constructor of your AsyncTask and set `mylat` and `mylong` as variables in that class
2. or pass them to the doInBackground method directly.

   ```
   ... extends AsyncTask<Double, ProgressType, ReturnType> {
       protected ReturnType doInBackground(Double... params) {
           mylat = params[0];
           mylong = params[1];
           List addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(mylat, mylong, 1);
           ...
       }
       ...
   }
   ```

   and call it with `execute(mylat, mylong);`

Comment: I tried this.  Got errors.  It sounds workable though.  Here is the code I have.  (mylat, and mylong are declared globally and there are two seperate get methods for these, so the other class <that sends the sms message> can get them)      http://pastebin.com/9b8Q3mFc

Comment: Your AsyncTask should be another class, don't inherit it in your main class. Example with an inner class: http://pastebin.com/2F0NEbUh

Comment: Got this Redh3ad, thanks for your help.  Was driving me up the wall for about 3 days straight!

Answer (score 1):

You can override the constructor of your AsyncTask class in that way that you can pass `mylat` and `mylong` as parameters. In the constructor you save the parameters as member variables of the AsyncTask. Doing this, you should be able to access them within the doInBackground() method.

Another thing is, you should think about if you really need a location listener. Perhaps the [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) and its method [getLastKnownLocation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29) will also do the job, if you only need the current location on certain moments. Then you can also determine the current position within the doInBackground() method. But be please read the documentation of [getLastKnownLocation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29) if it really fits your needs. If you need an update everytime the device moves, you will have to use the location listener.

Comment: Thanks Flo, yes I do need the location listener.  The Async Task works great, but because the class that sends the address in sms messages cant see the mylat=loc.getLatitude(); (which is in special required method onLocationChanged) the sms class seems to only see the global, null mylat/mylong variables, therefore cannot resolve an address when calling the get methods for mylat/mylong from the main class.